# Want to put a switch in for light that has a pull chain, and also want to Add outlet

Tags: receptacle

Putting a switch for light and adding outlet

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the existing boxes please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more detail about your situation.

Comment: would the outlet be switched or always on? If switched, it's simpler and can likely re-use most of the existing wiring.